# is there any $_REQUEST equivalent in jquery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

as we use `$_REQUEST` in `PHP` to receive  post/get values, I'm looking for a similar function/key to receive `values` sent through `$.ajax`.. in `java script`/`j query`

example:

```
<script>

function do_something(){
// here i want the value sent using ajax
return term;
}

$('#input').keyup(function(){
var term=$(this).val();
$.ajax({
url:do_something(),// << is this possible?? or should i try 
//url:do_something(term)  //<< this???
dataType:'json',
data:{term:term},
results:function(data){
alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}
});

</script>
```

Comment: jQuery does not receive post/get values. jQuery is not a server-side language. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: any other possibilities to pass values??

Comment: jQuery isn't a language at all, it's a library.  It could be used in a node.js environment in which case it would be running serverside.

Comment: You have set your dataType to JSON. Do you know what that does, what JSON is and what's an HTTP *response*? It seems there's a knowledge gap present here, you'll need to read up on the things I mentioned which will show you why you can't have such a mechanism in JS.

Comment: How does the `data:{term:term}` bit you already have fail to meet your needs?

Answer (score -2):

`document.location.search` can get GET values of the current URL.

When used like this:

```
document.location.search.substr(1).split("&");
```

you can get an array containing all GET keys and values like `key=value`. Then by simply splitting them on `=` you get the value.

Comment: I believe it's because this doesn't answer the question

Comment: Well, it does. OP asked how to get GET and/or POST values in JS. This answer shows how to get GET values.

Comment: I think you're confusing GET/POST parameters `values sent through $.ajax` with URL parameters of the current page

Comment: When an ajax request is sent to a page, with GET parameters, the code provided can get the values of the ajax GET request

Comment: @GeenHenk No, it cannot. Ajax cannot be "sent to a page" - only to the server. Even if you use node.js on the server side, your answer will also not work.

Comment: The OP (who is severely lacking knowledge) wants to know how to receive POST/GET in jQuery's `$.ajax`. However, those variables that PHP accesses via superglobal `$_REQUEST` are already constructed within the javascript so they are available since it's JS that **sends** them. So, if there's the one who **sends** - how can that one **receive** POST or GET? The reply format is JSON, any data that has to be passed **back** is available in the JSON format, and thus in his `data` variable supplied to the success callback. TL;DR - you didn't answer the question.

Comment: @N.B. chill dude, calm down.. I'm done with the problem i found the solution, i was trying to get data for Select2, using a JSON which has created by PHP while loading the page.. i'm using Reg Ex to find the matching data in that json in `do_something()` function, and its returning a filtered JSON. any way i asked the question in a stupid way..that was my fault.. i found the solution.